# How can I calculate the number of equivalence classes of this relation?

Tags: function, discrete-mathematics

Let S =  {1,2,3,....,8}. Consider the power set X = P(S) and the equivalence relation on X according to which two elements of X are equivalent if they have the same size. How many equivalence classes are there?

Comment: Not really a programming question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about discrete math, which is more appropriate at math.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

Each equivalence class of this relation will consist of a collection of subsets of X that all have the same cardinality as one another. Since |X| = 8, there are 9 different possible cardinalities for subsets of X, namely 0, 1, 2, ..., 8. Therefore, there are 9 different equivalence classes.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Those who are frustrated searching how to find number of equivalence classes here you go:

Number of equivalent classes is equal to number of state in minimal DFA.